# reg ex only for letters, dashes and spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I feel stupid but I'm hacking my mind over this stupid small thingy.

I have this regex to accept only alphabet chars.

I need it to accept also dashes and spaces.

```
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
```

Please explain also what is doing what, this regex is very confusing :@

Cheers!

Comment: try using a tool like http://www.regexr.com/ to develop your regex

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/ - good place to visualize the regex

Comment: [Regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5BA-Za-z%20-%5D%2B%24%2F) is also a great tool because it builds graphical "railroad diagrams" that are easy to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var letters = /^[A-Za-z -]+$/;
```

And to explain it:

```
/          Begin Regexp
^          Matches the start of a line
[          Begins a character group, matches anything in the group
    A-Z    Any letter between capital A and Z inclusive.
    a-z    Any letter between lower case a and z inclusive.
    " "    A space
    -      A litteral hyphen
]          Ends character group
+          Matches one or more of the previous thing(the character group)
$          Matches the end of the line
/          Ends regexp
```

Answer (score 1):

```javascript
var lettersDashesAndSpaces = /^[A-Za-z -]+$/;
// beginning of line ─────────┘│        │││
// any of... ──────────────────┴────────┘││
// ...letters A-Z and a-z                ││
// ...space                              ││
// ...dash                               ││
// one or more of the "any of" items ────┘│
// end of line ───────────────────────────┘
```

The trick is that the construct `[...]` defines a "character class", meaning "any character listed between the square brackets"; however, you can also include ranges (e.g. `A-Z`, meaning "any letter between 'A' and 'Z').

You simply need to add the "space" and "hyphen" characters to the character class.  A hyphen at the end let's the regex engine know that you are not defining a range but instead want a literal hyphen character.

See also on [regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5BA-Za-z%20-%5D%2B%24%2F).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var lettersSpacesDashes = /^[a-z -]+$/i;
```

See it in action: http://www.regexr.com/38tff